# Disabling Ajax in JQuery Mobile not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-mobile

This is header:

```
<script src="/blog/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/blog/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/blog/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/blog/media/system/js/caption.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/blog/media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/blog/plugins/system/jcemediabox/js/jcemediabox.js?f164ea24e8567d41a795089153b69cd9" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/blog/templates/qkiz3-mobile/js/jquery-mobile-config.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/blog/templates/qkiz3-mobile/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Content of jquery-mobile-config.js:

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function() {
  $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
```

Ajax is enabled and I cant disable it with jquery-mobile-config.js script. Chrome Developer Tool report error with this script: **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using? Use 1.9 at least and remove migrate and no conflict libraries.

Comment: Version 1.11.1. After exclude jquery-noconflict.js library everything work like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery-noconflict.js causes problem. After delete line with this library Ajax stops working.